# IronPython Console Error on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, console, ironpython

I recently installed ironpython 2.6.1 on my windows 7 machine. I wrote a program on an XP machine and everything works perfectly there. But when I try running ironpython or the ironpython console on windows 7, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception
    at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Shell.ConsoleHost.Run(Strinf[] args)
    at PythonConsoleHost.Main(String[] args)
```

I couldn't seem to find an example of this error online relating to IronPython. Does anyone know what may be causing it?

Comment: Do the XP and Windows 7 machines have/use the same .NET runtimes?

Comment: An SEHException is a structured exception handling exception.  Basically some unmanaged component is throwing an exception in native code.  I'd suggest running under windbg (http://www.windbg.org/) and seeing what exceptions it reports in the output window.  You can then break on whatever the weird exception is and see where it's coming from.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler Yes, they are both using 4.0.3